# selenium python continue after NoSuchElementException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have problem of going through selenium exception: NoSuchElementException.

code example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*)
    popup.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

with this i get crash on Django framework with above error type. What i need is to go through this exception and continue program.
One option is to use:

```
except:
    pass
```

but i need to collect exceptions elements.

Overall element is found by browser but can't be clicked:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" rel="nofollow">...</a> is not clickable at point (654, 570).
```

Thank You for any suggestions.

Comment: is there any errors that you are seeing? i suggest to add explicit wait for the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without try..catch.
Check the length of the elements and if more that 0 then go to if block and execute else whatever you want to do.

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*'))>0:
    popup =browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
    popup.click()
else:
    print("pass")
```

---

Or you can simply use if block.

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*'))>0:
    popup =browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
    popup.click()
```

**Edited**:

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*'))>0:
    popup =WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*")))
    popup.click()
else:
    print("pass")
```

Comment: that will work but not in this case, because element is found but selenium can't click on it: Element is not clickable at point (654, 570)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi : Check my edited answer.Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

Comment: that will not always work, because in some cases clickable element was hidden behind popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add exception that will handle click error.

```
errors = []

try:
    popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
    popup.click()
except NoSuchElementException as err:
    errors.append(err.msg)
    pass
except ElementNotInteractableException as err:
    errors.append(err.msg)
    pass
```